# Use array or JSON to keep track of unique list

Tags: javascript, performance, parse-platform, lookup

I have an object in Parse .com database that can receive thumbs up votes. I want to keep track of which users have provided a thumbs up to prevent the same user doing it again. I am thinking of adding a field to my object called "voters" that will hold the list of voting users.

Should this be an array of usernames or a JSON with keys as the usernames?

Why would I use an array if i could use a json map and do O(1) lookup of the names on the keys?

`ie object.voters[uername] = undefined then no votes`?

Answer (score 1):

Use Array if you need just the name of the voter .

Use Json if you need more info than just the name .

Why is that if u need just the name just making an array with the voter names first will be easy second it will be faster t process .

but if you need something like 
`voter={"name":"foo","age":"25"}`
 as you see we can use the powerof json to save multiple info about one user and anyway each voter must be within a single array so you can iterate over them

UPDATE---
to find the index of a name in an array just use `array.indexOf("the name")` what this will return is the index number of the name if the name doesnt exist it will return just -1 so a simple if else can handle this

UPDATE---

And [here](http://jsperf.com/arr-vs-obj-lookup) i found a performance test to compare which is faster to lookup whitin an array or an object and seems arrays still win this.

And [here](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/07/20/javascript-array-and-object-lookup-speeds/) is another source for reading

Comment: yes but that means each time i want to find a user need to search the array, whereas in a json i can access the item immediately using the key?

Comment: @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian im updating the question

Comment: my concern is not the code, im concerned about the lookup time on the array (how to indexOf work internally?) compared to a key lookup

Comment: heres the test to compare loop and indexof and it is faster https://jsperf.com/js-for-loop-vs-array-indexof/39

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me... When you use a map, the key is the index that points tot he location in the array directly - this will be faster than any lookup method on an array. Am I  missing something with regards to how accessing JSON properties works?

Comment: well i got it @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian updating the question